# Auto-Login Automation Anywhere

Tags: authentication, automation, autologin, automationanywhere

I can't auto-login, I have all the fields that are necessary to activate the auto login and the service running ... how can I operate the auto login when my computer is in the locked state?

[Image Error when I'm blocked and the task is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsNPI.png)

But I have the service is running:

[Image Service running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAcFL.png)

And my option checked:

[Image option check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIgMc.png)

[Image 2 option check](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WtxHT.png)

Comment: You used the `robot` tag which is for physical robots. What does this question have to do with physical robots?

Comment: @BryanOakley It's Robot Process Automation (RPA), It has to do with robot in my opinion.

Comment: The `robot` tag documentation says it's specifically for physical robots: _"Questions related to physical robots in general should use this tag. For other topics, please use one of the more specific tags listed in the wiki of this tag, if appropriate. You may also consider asking your question on robotics stack exchange: http://robotics.stackexchange.com/."_